# Infinite loop with larger values

Tags: python, python-3.x, infinite-loop

This is a program I made to calculate credit card balance. It seems to run inconsistently because some values cause it run in an infinite loop, while with other values the code runs fine. I think it must be something wrong with the way I'm using my for loops.

```
monthlyPayment = 0

monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate /12
newbalance = balance
month = 0

while newbalance > 0:
    monthlyPayment += .1
    newbalance = balance

    for month in range(1,13):
        newbalance -= monthlyPayment
        newbalance += monthlyInterestRate * newbalance
        month += 1
print("Lowest Payment:" + str(round(monthlyPayment,2)))
```

Comment: We still don't know the value of `annualInterestRate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while newbalance > 0:
    monthlyPayment += .1
    newbalance = balance
```

Here is your problem. As long as `balance` is greater than 0, `newbalance` will always be reset to `balance` and the while loop will evaluate as true and will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: It should be noted that `newbalance` is modified inside the `for` loop, thus it is possible that it assumes a negative value. It depends if the `-=` operation will decrease the newbalance more than the following `+=` operation, or not.

Comment: @Corgs How does this explain why the code works fine when the value of `balance` is moderate (not too large of a number)? It doesn't make sense in my mind why large numbers cause it to malfunction.

Comment: like @heltonbiker referred too, if `monthlypayment` is larger than `balance ` or when summed up is larger than `newbalance`, inside the for loop, the condition in the while loop will fail because you are doing `-=`. Not saying that it *couldn't* happen with larger numbers, it's just not as likely.

Answer (score 0):

You must make the testing condition of `while` become `False`. Since it is `newbalance > 0`, it should eventually emerge from the `for` loop with a positive value.

Comment: It looks like you are paying too much, or your interest rate is too low ;o)

Comment: The testing condition has to become `False`. The loop repeates while it's `True`.

Comment: @heltonbiker What do I need to change in my code to accomplish this?

Comment: @EllaP the code itself doesn't have an absolute error. Your problem is with the values. I don't know the values of `montlyPayment` and `monthlyInterest`, but they should make the value of `newBalance` increase.

Comment: It's a bit like saying to an object: "move in free-fall untill you hit the ground", but the object you release is a gas balloon that moves upwards and never hits the ground, so your "while falling" lasts forever :o)